# threejs sketching tool with cube geometry

Tags: three.js

I am working on a sketching tool with the help of threejs. This tool should allow users drawing cubes at any direction. I partially achieved this but still **when I scale an object at negative direction the face colors get inverted**. I am looking for a solution to avoid color inversion. mean the cube should be the same at both positive and negative scaling.

Please kindly help..!!

Thanks in advance.

Scaling at positive direction.

[image: Scaling at positive direction]

Scaling at negative direction.

[image: Scaling at negative direction]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If scaling negatively has unwanted artifacts, why don't you just avoid doing it? Your cubical meshes are symmetrical, so there no desired behaviour as far as I can tell.

In other words, display -50, but scale by the absolute value (50).

```
scale.set(Math.abs(scale)...)
```

If you really -do- need geometry flipping, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625199/threejs-geometry-flipping).

Comment: Thanks Paul-Jan, this workaround solves my problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you draw cube and scale it lower than, it vertices are being drawn inside.  you can set box's material as double sided.

I assume you are using MeshBasicMaterial

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side:THREE.DoubleSide});
var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometryInstance,  material);
```

Comment: Thanks @Selim, but  still it did not resolve the problem even after applying this side property..!!

Comment: `cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
    cubeGeo.translate(2.5, 2.5, 2.5);  cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    cubeMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
    cubeMaterial.transparent = false;
    cubeMaterial = [loadTexture('textures/busrun/rightLeft.jpg'), 
    loadTexture('textures/busrun/rightLeft.jpg'), 
     loadTexture('textures/busrun/topBottom.jpg'),      loadTexture('textures/busrun/topBottom.jpg'), 
     loadTexture('textures/busrun/rightLeft.jpg'),      loadTexture('textures/busrun/rightLeft.jpg')  
    ]; `